# How to correctly write date from google spreadsheet to an AWS RDS database using google apps script?

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, amazon-rds

I have a google apps script like the following:

```
// Initialize DB variables
var address = 'my-test-db.abcdefg.rds.amazonaws.com'
var user = 'my_name'
var password = 'my_password'
var db = 'my_db'
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db + '?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8'

function testDateTime() {

  // Read data inside the sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var cell = sheet.getRange('D3:D3')
  var testDateStr = cell.getValue()
  Logger.log(testDateStr)  // Fri Mar 09 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2018
  var testDate = new Date(testDateStr)

  // Prepare SQL statement
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password)
  var sql = 'UPDATE my_table SET start_date=? WHERE id=1'
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)
  stmt.setTimestamp(1, Jdbc.newTimestamp(testDate.getTime()))
  Logger.log(testDate.getTime())  // 1.5205248E12

  // Execute SQL statement
  stmt.execute()  // The value inside my AWS RDS is 2018-03-08 08:00:00

  // Clean up
  stmt.close()
  conn.close()

}
```

It reads the content of a cell in `D3:D3` from a google spreadsheet, then writes the value of it to an AWS RDS.

When the value in the sheet is `2018/03/09`, I found that `2018-03-08 08:00:00` got written to the database. Why is there a time difference between these two values?

The [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) says that `1.5205248E12` belongs to 2018-03-09 UTC+8.

Here's my `appsscript.json` file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Taipei",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

The timezone of `Asia/Taipei` is `UTC+8`.

The `time_zone` parameter of my AWS RDS is also set to `Asia/Taipei`.

The column type of `start_date` is `datetime DEFAULT NULL`.

I don't understand why there's a time difference between the value of google spreadsheet cell and that of `start_date` in my AWS RDS.

Comment: @pnuts, both are 'Asia/Taipei'.

Comment: Well, what time zone is AWS reporting?

Comment: I would check your database's time zone

Comment: @tehhowch, the only thing I find that is related to time zone is the `time_zone` parameter, which is set to `Asia/Taipei`. Is there any other time zone related parameter in AWS?

Comment: `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` outputs 2 `Asia/Taipei`s.

Comment: It seems that this error is caused by [JDK-6596714](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6596714).